# How do I select a specific element in a table depending on the text

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-ide

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:200px;">Features</th>
      <th style="width:300px;">Settings for this entry round</th>
      <th style="width:300px;">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);"> is_team_round </td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
      <div>
        <select id="account_3" onchange="changeAccount(3);" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
      <div> </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center;"> Yes </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> is_file_uploads </td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
      <div>
        <select id="account_4" onchange="changeAccount(4);">
      <div> </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center;"> Yes </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I select the ID account 3 depending if the text is is_team_round?

I tried `//td[contains(text(), 'is_team_round')]`, and it selects is_team_round.

Then I tried `//td[contains(text(), 'is_team_round')]//select[@id='account_3']`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the xpath:

```
//tr[./td[contains(text(), 'is_team_round')]]//select
```

This says to find the row (tr) that has the cell (td) with text 'is_team_round". Then find the select list inside that row.

Note: Your original solution did not work because it tried to find a select list inside the cell containing the text. As seen in the HTML, the select list is not inside the same cell. Hence, the need to use a common ancestor (ie the row).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that I didn't accepted this as an answer. I always come back to this because I don't remember the correct way to do this. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using 2 nested jquery's .each() function to iterate over the cells, and then testing the values with jquery's .val() or .html() function to get and compare the values.check out those functions uses and syntax at jquery.com.
hope it helped

Answer (score -1):

```
  $("#table").find("tbody td").eq('is_team_body');
```

id try something like this

Comment: What language is this? It doesn't look familiar to me

Comment: its jquery  [Jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-select-specific-row-col-tr-td)